# ServerSocket doesn't appear in Netstat?

Tags: java, sockets, server, serversocket, netstat

Very confused, I just posted this question but deleted it because I made many mistakes. Alright well here goes again! I have a server program in java below. When I run it I expect to see some sort of presence in netstat, but I see nothing. Here are some screen shots:

Before running server: https://www.dropbox.com/s/upo9ndbzuxbk9j1/Screenshot%202014-12-24%2002.25.49.png?dl=0

After running server (server running in top right terminal, bottom right is client and obviously left is netstat): https://www.dropbox.com/s/05urjvz3lskvzkc/Screenshot%202014-12-24%2002.28.24.png?dl=0

Somewhat long but here is the server (I run it with 63400):

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class JavaTest2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        if (args.length != 1) {
            System.err.println("Usage: java KnockKnockServer <port number>");
            System.exit(1);
        }

        int portNumber = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);

        try (
                ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(portNumber);
                Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
                PrintWriter out =
                        new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
        ) {

            String inputLine, outputLine;

            // Initiate conversation with client
            KnockKnockProtocol kkp = new KnockKnockProtocol();
            outputLine = kkp.processInput(null);
            out.println(outputLine);

            while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                outputLine = kkp.processInput(inputLine);
                out.println(outputLine);
                if (outputLine.equals("Bye."))
                    break;
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Exception caught when trying to listen on port "
                    + portNumber + " or listening for a connection");
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}

class KnockKnockProtocol {
    private static final int WAITING = 0;
    private static final int SENTKNOCKKNOCK = 1;
    private static final int SENTCLUE = 2;
    private static final int ANOTHER = 3;

    private static final int NUMJOKES = 5;

    private int state = WAITING;
    private int currentJoke = 0;

    private String[] clues = { "Turnip", "Little Old Lady", "Atch", "Who", "Who" };
    private String[] answers = { "Turnip the heat, it's cold in here!",
            "I didn't know you could yodel!",
            "Bless you!",
            "Is there an owl in here?",
            "Is there an echo in here?" };

    public String processInput(String theInput) {
        String theOutput = null;

        if (state == WAITING) {
            theOutput = "Knock! Knock!";
            state = SENTKNOCKKNOCK;
        } else if (state == SENTKNOCKKNOCK) {
            if (theInput.equalsIgnoreCase("Who's there?")) {
                theOutput = clues[currentJoke];
                state = SENTCLUE;
            } else {
                theOutput = "You're supposed to say \"Who's there?\"! " +
                        "Try again. Knock! Knock!";
            }
        } else if (state == SENTCLUE) {
            if (theInput.equalsIgnoreCase(clues[currentJoke] + " who?")) {
                theOutput = answers[currentJoke] + " Want another? (y/n)";
                state = ANOTHER;
            } else {
                theOutput = "You're supposed to say \"" +
                        clues[currentJoke] +
                        " who?\"" +
                        "! Try again. Knock! Knock!";
                state = SENTKNOCKKNOCK;
            }
        } else if (state == ANOTHER) {
            if (theInput.equalsIgnoreCase("y")) {
                theOutput = "Knock! Knock!";
                if (currentJoke == (NUMJOKES - 1))
                    currentJoke = 0;
                else
                    currentJoke++;
                state = SENTKNOCKKNOCK;
            } else {
                theOutput = "Bye.";
                state = WAITING;
            }
        }
        return theOutput;
    }
}
```

Now when I run the client I can see the presence in netstat at the very top, the two sockets as my server and client running on same computer. But still no server socket :(

Screenshot: https://www.dropbox.com/s/bnrbyk41mjob5bg/Screenshot%202014-12-24%2002.25.53.png?dl=0

Code for client (ran with 127.0.0.1 64300):

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class JavaTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        if (args.length != 2) {
            System.err.println(
                    "Usage: java KnockKnockClient <host name> <port number>");
            System.exit(1);
        }

        String hostName = args[0];
        int portNumber = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);

        try (
                Socket kkSocket = new Socket(hostName, portNumber);
                PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(kkSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader(kkSocket.getInputStream()));
        ) {
            BufferedReader stdIn =
                    new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            String fromServer;
            String fromUser;

            while ((fromServer = in.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println("Server: " + fromServer);
                if (fromServer.equals("Bye."))
                    break;

                fromUser = stdIn.readLine();
                if (fromUser != null) {
                    System.out.println("Client: " + fromUser);
                    out.println(fromUser);
                }
            }
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            System.err.println("Don't know about host " + hostName);
            System.exit(1);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Couldn't get I/O for the connection to " +
                    hostName);
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance to anyone who takes the time to figure it out!

I think it may just be netstat but I still want to know why as when I run lsof -i :64300
it shows my java process, when only the server is running. And when I run that with everything I see 3 (as you can see in the left terminal in this screenshot https://www.dropbox.com/s/1focc9dmhkidtan/Screenshot%202014-12-24%2002.52.22.png?dl=0). I cancel the netstat after it shows me what I "think" is relevant because I cannot interpret the rest. I dont know if its there. Hopefully someone helps!

Ok I am just finding out more as I write this cause I cannot post for 90 minutes but, now when I use intellij idea and run it there. Just the server, there is no change, but when I add the client I see everything!

before anything: https://www.dropbox.com/s/akupewmprcld0b3/Screenshot%202014-12-24%2002.59.05.png?dl=0

server: https://www.dropbox.com/s/uvxmz0jvjozbkyy/Screenshot%202014-12-24%2002.59.34.png?dl=0

client + server: https://www.dropbox.com/s/bssa16s1n3adwdq/Screenshot%202014-12-24%2003.00.00.png?dl=0

What is going on.... I also see 6 localhosts instead of 3... God this is interesting or I am just making one very silly mistake. But I am starting to doubt any of this matters.

Comment: netstat omits listening sockets by default. There's an -l option or -all for all sockets.

Comment: I'm not a `netstat` expert but I noticed that your netstat listing has the title "Active Internet connections."  Perhaps a server that is only listening is not "active" yet?

Comment: Looks like I got it in one.  The first comment indicates another solution: make sure you read the documentation on the tools you use so you know how they actually work.

Comment: Sure enough you were correct. When I ran it with -all I saw it but netstat -l I didn't. Thanks

Comment: It shows up as  *.64300. I can see the other localhosts before the port number so why does this one have a *? I tried googling but couldn't find anything.

Comment: You're not binding your server socket to a specific IP address, so it shows up as '*'. Again, this is almost certainly mentioned in the `netstat` documentation.

Answer (score 0):

netstat omits listening sockets by default. There's an -l option or -all for all sockets. – laune